# How to find propagation vector r using broadcast elimination method?

Tags: c

Could someone help me to find the propagation vector (r) using data broadcast elimination method?

[image is extracted from, "Elimination of the Computational Broadcast : An Application to the QR Decomposition Algorithm" by Marjan Guˇsev1, David J.Evans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtuWc.png)

I'm not clear that how the propagation vector r is directly taken from dependancy matrix d. If anyone know how this comes please let me know it or give me the supported documentation.

Actually the above stated paper provide a reference for understanding data broadcast elimination method. but I'm also in a trouble when finding that reference too. I will give that reference[2] in APF format and if someone will found that, let me too.

[2] : M. Guˇsev and J. Tasiˇc, “Method for data broadcast elimination,” in Parallel Computing 91, Int. Conf., London, North Holland, Sept 3-6, 1991.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this part of the paper is confusing. Here is what I finally figured out:

One iteration produces a datum, and broadcast it to many other iterations (consumers) with a dependence d2=[1 -1; 0 1]p=Ap for each consumer p.

Assume two consumers p1 and p2. The producer of p1 is p1-Ap1=(I-A)p1, and the producer of p2 is p2-Ap2=(I-A)p2. But as we assumed above, this is broadcast and there is only 1 producer. So (I-A)p1=(I-A)p2. Then (I-A)(p1-p2)=[0 1; 0 0] (p1-p2)= 0. Solve this equation, and we see that p1-p2 must equal [*, 0] where * is any value. The minimum of * is 1. So the propagation vector is [1, 0].